# How to smartly encode arbitrary metadata into a UUID?

Tags: algorithm, uuid

(This algorithm is for an iPhone app I am working on, if that helps the context at all.)

We need to make UUIDs to uniquely identify some products.  Usually this is as simple as assigning unique numbers, but we also want to encode metadata INTO our UUID.  Our API only allows us ONE field, so we want to use the UUID field as both a unique identifier and a metadata carrier.

Usually, you can just hodge-podge the data together with underscores, but we have one requirement that makes this difficult: one of the metadata items can be a list of *n* items.

Here is the metadata:

- Device type (~up to 16 discrete types)
- Min OS version supported (x.x.x format, where x is a number between 0-99)
- Min Binary (app) version supported (x.x.x format, where x is a number between 0-99)
- Any products that this product supersedes (list of *n* IDs, the format of which is part of this design problem)

**Limitations**

Our only technical limitation is that we can only use up to 128 alphanumeric characters (a-zA-Z0-9), including underscores, periods, and hyphens, to represent the UUID (it's an API).

**Use Cases**

Here are a few use cases to explain what this algorithm will help solve:

1. A user buys product A and product B.  We later release product C, which is a package of products A+B together.  Via C's UUID, we want our application code to be able to determine that C is really A+B, and since the user already owns A+B, C will not appear on a list of available products.
2. A user has 2 devices, A and B.  Product C is not supported on device B, so when the user views products on device B, C should not be available to them, but it should be on device A.

**What I've Done Thus Far**

Device type should be easy- with 16 discrete types, I can bitmask that - 16 bits = 4 hex characters.  Simple enough.

Versioning is the same - I can pad each version segment (x.y.z) to 2 digits, and then just have 2 runs of 6 digits as the version information.

Where it is non-trivial is how to refer to previous product IDs.  Clearly, my memory space is limited - I only have 128 characters (and using the approaches above, I'd have only 112 characters left).  If I need a list of *n* items, I *will* run out of space.

Realistically *n<=5* is reasonable.  Any given product would supersede no more than 5 other products.

A fixed-length UUID is NOT a requirement.  And yes, one "cheap" solution is to daisy-chain the ID list together with underscores, but since many of the IDs will have to be hand-entered in the first place, we'd like to avoid using 128 bytes if we can avoid it.  Minimizing the UUID length should be a priority after correctness in the algorithm.

Another part that may make this difficult -- although the implementation of this isn't in the UUID itself but rather in the code -- is that if one of the superseded products was superseding something else, that needs to cascade down.

Any pointers on where I can start on this?

Comment: Yyou can encode 16 types in 1 hex character.

Comment: @bdares, wait.  I thought you were right, but then I realized that I want to be able to say "this product supports any SUBSET of those 16 devices", not just 1 of 16.  In the latter, case, you're correct.  So, what's the minimum space required to encode "X of 16" types where X is <= 16?

Comment: 1 hex character can be from 0-9, A, B, C, D, E, F... which are 16.  If each of the characters represents 1 type of device, then the device can identify its type with 1 hex character.

Comment: @bdares, correct.  But I'd like for a product to work on maybe 8 of those devices, and not the other 8.    I was thinking a bitmask of yes/no (2^16) = (2^4)^4 - hence why I thought I needed four characters.  It's not a 1-to-1 relationship between products & devices.  It's 1-to-n, in this case n = 16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinking in terms of decimal or hex digits is a bad idea, it just wastes sooo much space.

Your UUID alphabet has 65 (2*26+10+3) characters. So with n characters you can encode 65^n different values.
For example the x.x.x format (where x is a number between 0-99) has really just 100^3 different values, so it can be encoded with log65(100^3) ~ 3.31 = 4 characters.
So for the first three metadata you need 1+4+1=9 characters, or if you combine the three fields log65(100^3*100^3*16) ~ 7.28 = 8 characters.

For the product supersede cascading problem I would suggest splitting the UUID into two parts, the first part containing a short UUID and the second part the metadata. When you referer to a superseded product use the short UUID.

Comment: you're right, using the methods you've said here I can save some space.  I also agree w/ you about splitting the ID into 2 parts.  I will do that!  Do you have any recommendation on the last part, the superseded ID?  I want to have an ID that supersedes another as its own ID in its own right, so that's where I'm having trouble.  Any help there?

Comment: Use the short IDs in the supersede list, you don't need the metadata there. I don't know all the requirements but this solves both use cases. Have I missed something?

Comment: I re-read what you said and I think I see your point.  So, a UUID might look something like: (device,etc metadata)+(short UUID)+(references to other UUIDs)

Comment: the definition of the UUID is recursive, so if you use references to full UUIDs the length of the UUID could grow to arbitrary large which is really bad.

I suggest is to use:

(short UUID)+(device+os+binary metadata)+(reference to other **short** UUIDs)

Answer (score 1):

Does this data need to be human readable???

If not then maybe you should look at this as a problem of serializing a struct/object into a byte array with a max length of 128.

For example you could use the format (UID[int],Device[byte],ArrayLength[byte],ProductID01[int16],...), then take the resulting byte array and base64 it.  Or if you are posting this data and it doesn't need to be URL safe, then just send it as a char array (basically base256).  I don't know any of your limits, but you may adjust the datatypes based on the max ranges. For example, if you think the array length will never be larger than 16, then you could split a byte for DeviceType and ArrayLength.

Even better would be to use a serlization framework like protoBuf.  But I don't know if it's been ported to iOS yet.

Comment: Great question.  Yes, preferably, the data's human readable.  That said, I can always write a shell script or something that "spits out" a UUID after a user answers questions.  Preferably it'd be nice to be able to eyeball a UUID and get a general idea of it. 

I do like the idea of base64 as it does a decent job of obscuring the underlying format when the product_ids are in a place where a human can look at them (it is an API).

Thanks.